# How to set dialogflow fulfillment response json context without using webhook client?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to create a rich response to Facebook integration using Dialogflow fulfillment. I tried using webhook but it's not working and then I try below way directly using response and now I am facing this context binding issue.

I tried below

```
let responseJson = {};

    let rich = [
      {
        'text': {
            'text': [
                text
            ],
        },
        'platform': 'FACEBOOK'
      },
    ];

    responseJson.fulfillmentMessages = rich;

    responseJson.outputContexts = context;

    response.json(responseJson);
```

my context JSON

```
{ name: 'MAINTENANCE_REQUEST', lifespan: 5, parameters: { maintenanceRequest: maintenanceRequest }}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a custom payload without a webhook, go to your intent, and scroll to the bottom where it says "responses". Click on the plus sign (picture) and click on the facebook option. Click on the add responses -> custom payload. The format and available fields for the custom payload are described [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents#message). Delete the "Text Response" if it's there so the custom payload will be the only one to be returned.

[image: Dialogflow console]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do this using fulfillment code

Comment: what do you mean? The example code you give above, can go inside the payload